# bootp setup in Linux

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dhcp-server, bootp

We are currently replacing our old HP-UX system which does bootp for some equipment that we use here in our facility. I have the old bootptab file from the unix server and ISC dhcp server installed on the Ubuntu server. There are some things in the bootptab file that I'm not quite sure how to deal with in the dhcp server. Here is an example of one of our machines. Took out some info.

```
name:\
    hn:\
    bf=bootstrap/vmechgr:\
    hd=/bootp:\
    ht=ether:\
    ha=mac Address:\
    ip=IP Address:\
    vm=rfc1084:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use-host-decl-names on; #hn

host name {
    filename "bootstrap/vmechgr"; #bf
    option root-path "/bootp"; #hd
    hardware ethernet macAddr; #ha
    fixed-address IPaddr;      #ip
 }
```

I am not sure if you need 'ht' and 'vm' anymore.

Anyway you may meet surprises because ISC DHCPD is quite far from bootpd and this can be vendor-specific. In that case you may just use 'tcpdump -s0 -vvv port bootpc or port bootps' on Linux server and post both request and reply here.

Also, you also can continue using bootptab - NetBSD still have bootpd in stock. Besides, CMU dhcpd still support reading bootptab.

Comment: Looking into the CMU dhcp server. I found it on the princeton university site. Having some issues getting it installed, though. Do you know if there's a way to install it using apt install or do I have to build it?

Comment: The best way I know for linux is to install it via pkgsrc system. Look  to https://www.pkgsrc.org/ This is very specific but you may find it useful. However my best recommendation to replace old HP-UX is to use BSD, because its much closer to old HP-UX. My personal choice is NetBSD and it have both bootpd in stock and cmu-dhcpd in native pkgsrc system. You may run it in VM in your Ubuntu box though.

Comment: Yet another opinion - if I were you I would try to replace bootpd with isc-dhcpd as you initially wanted to. That may be hard once, but you will get rid of all old software at once.

Comment: Do I only need to put the line "use-host-decl-names on;" Once and then just list all the pieces of equipment below it?

Comment: Below or after - this do not make sense. Anywhere outside host declaration it become global variable for isc-dhcpd behavior. Usually global options go first. You will also need "allow bootp;" global option and subnet declaration for your network. This together (and hosts declarations) will make initial config for you to start with.